# Using variable as table name in SQL pdo query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I found a way to use a variable as table name in a pdo query.

However, I would like to know if the piece of code below is safe.

```php
function buildQuery($CheckInput)
{
    switch($CheckInput) {
        case $CheckInput == 'user':
            $TableName = 'user';
            break;

        case $CheckInput == 'guest':
            $TableName = 'guest';
            break;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $TableName";
    return $sql;
}
```

The function is used like this:

```php
if (isset($_POST['DropDownChoice']) AND ($_POST['DropDownChoice'] == 'user' OR $_POST['DropDownChoice'] == 'guest'))  {
    $sql = buildQuery(htmlspecialchars($_POST['DropDownChoice']));
}
```

If `$CheckInput` is never true in the switch then `$TableName` will be undefined.
What will happen to the SQL query?

All the examples I found do not use the default case, is there a reason?

Comment: Initiate the variable `$TableName` above your switch with the default table if u are going to use the switch like that

Comment: No `default:` on the switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set default to make sure to get table name

```
function buildQuery($CheckInput)
{

    switch($CheckInput)                 
    { 
        case 'user':
            $TableName = 'user';
            break;

        case 'guest':
            $TableName = 'guest';
            break;

        default:
           $TableName = 'guest';

    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $TableName";
    return $sql;

}
```

Comment: Using a `switch` like that is perfectly valid. Can be useful if u need to check whether a variable is between ranges. [Example](https://ideone.com/82dHRv)

Comment: @DarkBee : `default:
           $TableName = 'guest';` would work then

Comment: no doubt about that. I'd only chain the last as `case 'guest': default: $TableName = 'guest';`